# vsftpd full anonymous access

Tags: configuration, vsftpd

I'm runnning vsftpd on Raspberry Pi, Debian 7.0.

I want to use it to do backups in my Home-LAN only, so security is not an issue (behind NAT/Firewall, only trusted users). I would like full access as anonymous user to a given path `/mnt/hd1` which has owner root and full rights 777.

My conf is currently

```
# cat /etc/vsftpd.conf
listen=YES
anonymous_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
anon_upload_enable=YES
anon_mkdir_write_enable=YES
anon_root=/mnt/hd1
```

With this I get the client error

```
500 OOPS: vsftpd: refusing to run with writable root inside chroot()
```

I tried adding

```
allow_writeable_chroot=YES
```

but then my vsftps doesn't start anymore.

How should I configure vsftpd to have full access to a given directory as an anonymous user?

Comment: Check this http://blog.waja.info/2013/05/13/500-oops-vsftpd-refusing-to-run-with-writable-root-inside-chroot/ or this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22420177/500-oops-vsftpd-refusing-to-run-with-writable-root-inside-chroot-login-faile

Comment: What do you see in your logs after you added `allow_writeable_chroot=YES`?

Answer (score 1):

```
500 OOPS: vsftpd: refusing to run with writable root inside chroot()
```

is a [bug](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=735191) in version 2.3.5, it was fixed in 3.0 but it is not available in Wheezy. See workaround in this Answer on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16102996/vsftpd-refusing-to-run-with-writable-root-inside-chroot):

> This blog here points out how to fix this problem.
>
> http://www.mikestechblog.com/joomla/operating-systems-section/operating-systems-ubuntu/155-500-oops-vsftpd-refusing-to-run-with-writable-root-inside-chroot.html
>
> The issue being that the user's root directory is writable. The
>   Frontier Group provides you with a fix on vsFTPd.
>
> Here are the steps to be taken (copy paste from the tutorial, in case
>   the link dies)
>
> ```
> login as root (or sudo..) and do the following:
>
> apt-get install python-software-properties
>
> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:thefrontiergroup/vsftpd
>
> sudo apt-get update
>
> sudo apt-get install vsftpd
>
> vi /etc/vsftpd.conf and add the following allow_writeable_chroot=YES
>
> sudo service vsftpd restart
> ```

Comment: The workaround you link has solutions not valid for Raspberry Pi, because vsftpd-3.0 is available in Raspbian repos.